# Where does Nest build go?

Tags: nestjs

Nest's documentation says that `nest build` compiles stuff "into an output folder".

It fails however to mention what output folder that is.

Is it `dist/`? Not sure, running the command also does not give any hints.

```
> nestest@0.0.1 build /Users/alper/Code/contrib/nestest
> nest build
```

Comment: Did you look at what's in the working directory after you run it, what's in the `.gitignore`, ...?

Comment: I don't have the project in git yet, so no.

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean it doesn't include an ignore file, depending on how you _created_ the project the template might include one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commonly, `nest build` will go to the `dist` directory, as is a pretty common practice with most typescript applications. As a hint, you can look at the `start:prod` script in the `package.json` and see that it points at `node dist/main` for the start point. This is configurable, though, by changing the `outDir` of your `tsconfig.json`. If you do end up changing it, make sure to update the `start:prod` script if you plan on using that when you deploy for production

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's outputting things into the location specified in `tsconfig.json`.